# iPhone - Creating Home Screen for App that show icons to launch other app with in app

Tags: iphone, user-interface, user-experience

I just wanted to know how can I create Home Screen after launching my App, that shows multiple icons/app buttons to launch other apps, just like the way iPhone home screen has multiple icons/pages that list app icons.

My app will have different features like map,dining, weather etc.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to launch other applications from your app or are you building these functions yourself?

Comment: yes, I am building my own functionality for every module. Basically it'll be a University App that lets students look up locations, dining center, get RSS feed etc.

Answer (score 2):

This type of functionality is not allowed by Apple.  That is any sort of desktop replacement or dashboard system is explicitly prohibited.

However, if you check out the Facebook iPhone app, you can see that  you could do something similar.  That is one app showing a grid of icons.  Each of the icon buttons launches a different view within the app itself.

This type functionality is allowed and is provided by the three20 library:

https://github.com/facebook/three20

This library was spun off from code created in the Facebook App.

Comment: thanks for the tip but I am not trying to replace any of iPhone functionality. All I want is to have the similar home screen for my app like iPhone home screen where it has application icons listed to launch an app or swipe to see next screen showing more app icons.

Comment: I see that now from you answering DerekH.  The three20 library provides the best starting point available.